# rank contact's phone numbers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, ranking

I'm trying to order or rank a contacts phone numbers in rails so that users can change the order of a phone number.  I'm using the nested form gem if that helps.

The idea is that I want to rank them based the order in which they come in.  so the user could move the phone number field up or down the list and then based on what position in the list the number is in, it would be ranked in that order.

so like it would be listed as
phone1
phone2
phone3
phone4

then the user could change the order to 
phone2
phone4
phone1
phone3

and rails would know to re order them, ie,
change phone2's rank to phone1
phone 4's rank to phone2
etc.

I could change the order on the front end, but what that feels like there could be issues
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd run with something like https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list to manage the ranking stuff, but as far as the front-end goes, your best bet is to either use hidden form fields for the ordering (and update their values via JS), or each time a number is moved (via some sort of javascript goodness), submit that to a controller via xhr and re-render the list of numbers as a partial.